# Access chat in Microsoft Teams after meeting

Tags: ms-office

Is there any way to access chats after a meeting in Microsoft Teams?

I have some kind of MS Teams app on my Macbook. I use it to join a MS Teams meeting when I'm invited to one.

However, it is not the 'complete' Teams app which also has chat, filesharing and other stuff. I am not part of some company team with a Active Directory account, so I cannot 'log in' to Teams. The app just opens when I click 'Join Meeting' from an invite.

So after I wave goodbye and exit the meeting, where to the chats go?

Answer (score 0):

Those chats are stored in the storage bucket belonging to the tenant that paid to host the meeting. As a guest to the meeting it’s up to the persons configuring teams server-side whether you get to participate in chat past the meeting time or just for the duration of the meeting.

I’ve found the in app help to be excellent, but we pay a lot for O365 and I believe our requests go into a priority queue. I would still recommend even free accounts try the help in app if you don’t have any other direct support resource for this situation.

Your app is the same as everyone’s -  it feature flags and subscriptions enable functions so that many people have different experiences in “the same app, same version”

Just like Office apps on macOS, it’s the same app for everyone, but the license you bring to it enables features based on which license Microsoft sees for your app/account. All you may need to do is pay more for your teams license if you need extra features.

In the paid version, the meeting chat is stored in the calendar, so as Microsoft adds features to the free tier, be sure to check in the calendar tab for past chats in case you do have access to them now or later.

Comment: 'As a guest to the meeting it’s up to the persons configuring teams ...' do you mean it is in *my* Teams configuration or in *their* Teams configuration?

Comment: @Ivana Person that sets up the meeting “owns” the data (or ties it to the admin account for their tenant). I’ve edited my answer so hopefully less typo and more clarity is added.

Comment: Thanks @bmike, so I may have access provided the person hosting the meeting has made them available to me, and the way to find out is to get the paid version (or wait for the feature to be added to the free version)?